# Maven: Why am I getting servlet-api-2.5

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-war-plugin

I'm creating a web application with Maven, and I'm having a problem - for some reason I get `servlet-api-2.5.jar` included, which gives weird exceptions. Removing this file from the WAR archive solves all problems, but I'm trying to understand *why* it's there in the first place. My <s>dependencies in the</s> complete `pom.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sillyfly.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webappDirectory>web</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` yields:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - org.sillyfly.webapp:Webapp:jar:0.1
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] org.sillyfly.webapp:Webapp:jar:0.1
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38:compile
[INFO] \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 26 12:12:32 IDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/515M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where there is no mention for `servlet-api-2.5.jar`. 
I'm now noticing it says `jar` and not `war`, so I guess my question is twofold: 
1. Are the JAR and WAR dependencies different, and if so how do I get Maven dependency plugin to show me the WAR dependencies?
2. How can I explicitly tell Maven *not* to include `servlet-api-2.5.jar`? I've tried adding an exclusion in various places, but since I don't know why it's there in the first place it's mostly a guessing game as to where to put the exclusion, and none of the places I've tried have worked.

`mvn --version` for referene:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-23)
Java version: 1.8.0_72-internal
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "4.4.0-1-amd64" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Edit: I updated to Maven 3.3.9 and I still get the exact same result. The only difference is that the dependency tree shows dependencies between the various apache taglibs libraries, but still no mention of servlet-api-2.5.

Comment: Have you tried to put <scope>provided</scope> to your javax.servlet dependency? By the way the artifact is not <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>?

Comment: If you are getting it at the first place, so why you removed it from the second?

Comment: No, it is [javax.servlet-api](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.servlet%7Cjavax.servlet-api%7C3.1.0%7Cjar). Setting it to `provided` doesn't change the resulting war. Just to be clear - I'm getting both 2.5 *and* 3.1 in the war, not just 2.5. It's just that 2.5 is wrong, and causes runtime exceptions.

Comment: @RomanC - I don't understand what you ask. Maven puts it in the WAR file, and I have to remove it, as it's the wrong version, thus causing the code to fail at runtime.

Comment: Please stop using [Maven 2 cause it's End Of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). Furthermore based on your example i can't reproduce this..cause i don't see `javax.serverlet-api` anywhere here..so i assume you are using a parent which contains supplemental dependencies or dependencyManagement or you have omitted some parts of your pom file...

Comment: I have updated the question to include the complete pom.xml. Also updated to the latest Maven version on Debian, which is 3.3.9 at the moment. Problem still persists.

Comment: Really strange.  Would you be able to post the output for `mvn -X war:war`?  We’re missing something here.

Comment: Thank you! I did this, and found the problem - for some reason my project sources had lib/ and classes/ folders in WEB-INF, which got copied to the target. The wrong files where coming from there. Still not sure why they were there in the first place (the folders), but I've removed them, and everything is working fine now.

Comment: @sillyfly add that as an answer. They probably came from Eclipse compiling the project as a non-maven project, should you have ever used that with your files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem from the information you gave, so the root cause must be somewhere else.

Do you see the extra servlet JAR when running `mvn package` from the command line, or could it be a strange effect of your IDE?

If the problem persists, try to reduce your app to a minimum and create a self-contained project e.g. on GitHub that people can look at.

By the way, you must never include the servlet API in `WEB-INF/lib` (not twice, and not even once). Always use Maven scope `provided` for the servlet API.

Comment: For some reason, both `servlet-api-2.5.jar` *and* `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` end up in `WEB-INF/lib`, even if I give the latter `<scope>provided</scope>`. I'm updating the question to include the complete `pom.xml`. Is there anything else that can affect Maven? The project was originally from Intellij, but I believe Maven only cares about what's in the `pom.xml`, correct?

Comment: I am running `mvn war:war` from the command line. Running `mvn package` creates a JAR, not a WAR, and this JAR contains no libraries whatsoever.

Comment: @sillyfly using `mvn war:war` with your pom puts libs javax.json-1.0.4.jar,
mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar,
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar,
taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar,
taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar in the lib folder. Nothing else. Something else must be happening here.

Comment: Do you have any clues as to where to look? Can I ask Maven exactly which configuration it uses? Running with `-f ./pom.xml` to make sure it uses the correct pom has the same results for me.

Comment: @sillyfly can you test using debug output (`mvn -X`) and also with an empty dependency repo? (`mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/testrepo`). At least the latter should be interesting. You can also try `mvn help:effective-settings` to get your current settings.

Comment: Problem solved - the filed where in the project's source folder for some reason. I've removed lib/ and classes/ from the source WEB-INF, and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Normally there is a dependency in your project that is depending on servlet-apî.jar.
The default behaviour of Maven is that i wiill try to import your dependency + the dependencies of the imported dependency. 
If you want to exclude a specific "sub-dependency", you can give maven a configuration like this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hpsworldwide.mbtrs.switch</groupId>
    <artifactId>DEPENDENCY</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was `lib/` and `classes/` folders in the source's `WEB-INF`, which contained the jars that got included. The folders were created due to faulty pom configuration (see below). Situation was visible after enabling Maven debug output (`mvn -X`) when running Maven.

Removing these folders solved all of my problems.

**Edit**: After getting the same folders again, I found out the root of the cause - I have used `<webappDirectory>`, when I should have used `<warSourceDirectory>`.